# Laravel make merged created_at and updated_at timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, timestamp, migration

In a **model** I have created custom timestamps:

```
const CREATED_AT = 'fil_ts';
const UPDATED_AT = 'fil_ts';
```

Basically the idea is that **CREATED_AT** timestamp will get updated whenever record is changed (***in other words: I would have just one timestamp which acts as created and updated timestamp***).

*How do I make these custom timestamps appear in the database's table trough migrations? Do I need to create them in the migration file when I create the table?*

---

**1. Do i need to define custom timestamps in migration like this**

```
$table->timestamp('fil_ts');
$table->timestamp('fil_ts');
```

**2. or like this**

```
$table->timestamps();
```

So far neither of these methods worked. With the first method I get an error that I can't have same named variables (which is logical, but I don't know other way how to make SINGLE timestamp act as CREATED_AT and UPDATED_AT).

If I use the second method it just creates default timestamps.

**My end goal**: a single custom timestamp that acts like created_at and updated_at. First it gets creation timestamp and then it keeps updated.

---

### Update

Even if the custom timestamps names are different I still get error when I run php artisan migrate:

**Timestamps in the model:**

```
   const CREATED_AT = 'file_created';
   const UPDATED_AT = 'file_updated';
```

**Timestamps in the migration:**

```
 $table->timestamp('file_created');
 $table->timestamp('file_updated');
```

> Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'file_updated'")

### Solution

**Code in the model:**
*Need to disable default timestamps*

```
public $timestamps = false; 
const CREATED_AT = 'fil_ts';
const UPDATED_AT = 'fil_ts';
```

**Code in the migration**

```
$table->timestamp('fil_ts');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model disable the default timestamp by writing the following code.

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

To create your own timestamp use this code.

This will create one timestamp column.

```
$table->timestamp('fil_ts');
```

Reference:https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations

Comment: Thank you! Never I would have thought first  I need to **disable** timestamps to have custom names working!..

Comment: Accept this is  Answer so that other find it helpful too.

Answer (score -1):

From Larval 8 you can use this format:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at');
```

This will only create the 'created_at' column, not 'updated_at'.